# Php and string analysis: how to remove comments recursively

Tags: php, string, analysis

I have a string with comments in it C-style like `test/* comment */`.
I would like to remove them, and I would like to get this as a result: `test`

I've done something working, but now I would like to be able to have comment into comment, and ignore "nested comment". For example I would like to make a function that removes comments in strings like `test/* co/* comment */mmen/* comment */t */` and would still return this as a result: `test`.

How would you do?

Comment: `preg_replace('|/\*.*?/\*|', '', $sTestString)` at a rough guess

Comment: @CD001 The last part, `/\*`  should be the other way round, `\*/`.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - good point, and I'm not sure, looking at it again, that `.*?` should be an ungreedy match I've a feeling it might only match 1 character, said it was a rough guess, should have RegExp 101'd it ... and I did just regexp101 it ... and I was right first time ... except for the end quote mark like you said :)

Comment: @CD001 If it was greedy then it would also consume the `*` before the last `/`, and then never find the end of the comment. Making it non-greedy makes it consume as few `*`s as possible, allowing the last part to match.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - yeah, it's almost 1am here, that's my excuse anyway, bed time I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regular expression that removes multi-line comments:

```
$text = preg_replace('%/\*.*?\*/%', null, $text);
```

Comment: I doesn't work. Try this exemple (which should return "je suis bon": `php -r 'echo preg_replace("%/\*.*?\*/%", null, "je suis bon /* et elle/* un peu moins*/ aussi */")."\n";'`

Comment: @OlivierPons The comment in your string is invalid; you cannot close a comment twice.